# log4net вывод на страницу aspx

Tags: c#, log4net

Есть веб проект, в котором используется log4net. Логи ведутся в текстовый документ в папку Log. Нужно сделать aspx страницу где будут показываться логи. Я ранее с логированием не работал и вижу это решение таким образом, что беру этот текстовый файл, распарсиваю и вставляю в страницу. Но мне это решение кажется неверным. Есть ли какие-то еще варианты вывода логов на страницу ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Никакого магического способа показать логи на странице не существует.

Вы настраиваете log4net, указывая ему с помощью аппендеров, куда писать логи. Список доступных аппендеров можно посмотреть на [офсайте](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html).

Соответственно если вы хотите отобразить логи на странице, вам нужно выбрать, куда их писать, затем считывать их оттуда. Текстовый файл и БД -- самые простые варианты, как мне кажется. Еще там есть AspNetTraceAppender, возможно он подойдет лучше (я с ASP.NET толком не знаком, поэтому точнее сказать не могу).